# Missing Logic in my code populating array creates duplicates - javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to figure out how to not duplicate objects in my array. Notice in the commentors data model, index 0 and 1 is duplicated because the insertproperty function i did an id compare which is ideal for a list with unique ids, but i still have to apply this in this situation to make sure im associating to the correct user.

Comments Data Model:

```
var comments = [{id:1, comment_text:"foo", user_id:1},
{id:2, comment_text:"bar", user_id:1},
{id:3, comment_text:"brew", user_id:2}];
```

Commentors Data Model when merged:

```
var commentors = [{id:1, name:"ed", comment_text:"foo"},
{id:1, name:"ed", comment_text:"foo"},
{id:2, name:"sue", comment_text:"brew"}];
```

DESIRED Result:

```
var commentors = [{id:1, name:"ed", comment_text:"foo"},
{id:1, name:"ed", comment_text:"bar"},
{id:2, name:"sue", comment_text:"brew"}];
```

---

```
$scope.insertProperty=function(){           
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.commentors.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<$scope.comments.length;j++){
                if($scope.commentors[i].id==$scope.comments[j].user_id)                               
                $scope.commentors[i].comment_text=$scope.comments[j].comment_text;                   
            }
        }
    }

$scope.commentors = [];
  var getUser = function(id) {
        UserService.GetUserById(id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {
          var data = angular.fromJson(data);   
          $scope.commentors.push(data);
          $scope.insertProperty();
        }).error(function(error, status) {
            //do something         
        });
    };

$scope.GetComments = function(){
PostService.GetComments($stateParams.id, $localStorage.auth_token)
          .success(function (data) {      
            var data = angular.fromJson(data);                 
            angular.forEach(data, function(user){
                getUser(user.user_id);})                       
          }).error(function(error, status) {
            //do something        
          });
    }
```

Comment: `getUser(user.user_id);` will be requested for each comments. So, I assume if there are 1000 comment you will request the same api 1000 times. This is not a good idea you can make new api/method which will get desired output which you want.

Comment: @Justcode hi i request the index range in chunks for my lazy loading... 0 - 10, 11 - 20, 21 - 30... for brevity i just showed what i believe is only necessary to understand the problem

Comment: You can do the same from backend make a new api in `PostService` which will pass the desire output pass the userid/parameters you want. and than you can perform the same.

Comment: @Justcode i don't have control over backend i can only make use of what I have

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.result=[];
$scope.insertProperty = function(){
for(var i=0; i<$scope.comments.length; i++)
{
  for(var j=0; j<$scope.commentors.length; j++)
 {
  if($scope.commentors[i].id==$scope.comments[j].user_id) 
  {
     $scope.result.push($scope.commentors[i].id, $scope.commentors[i].name, $scope.commentors[j].common_text);
  }
 }
}

$scope.commentors = $scope.result;
```